# How can I run touch screen games in non-touch Android PC?

Tags: applications, touchscreen, android-x86

I have installed Android ×86 KitKat a few days ago on my Lenovo G580 model-20157 PC. Everything works just fine, but when I installed a game, I could not play it since it was meant for touch screen and my PC doesn't support touch.

Answer (score 0):

You can play it with a trackpad or mouse most of the time.